# React Native maximum call stack size error

Tags: react-native

I am using `react-native-geolocation-service` in my project and got below error:

```
error: node_modules\react-native-geolocation-service\js\Geolocation.android.js: Maximum call stack size exceeded

"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-geolocation-service": "^3.1.0"
```

Could anyone help me fix it?

Comment: add the code how or where you are using `react-native-geolocation-service`